# Is there a "standard" Primary Key pool table implementation method?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Back in the "good o' days" I used Sybase's SQL Anywhere database. It had a feature to avoid collisions when multiple users created new records: A separate table of key values existed that would be used to dole out blocks of unique keys to client applications to be used in subsequent inserts into other tables. When the client's pool of keys gets low, the client requests another block of keys from the server. The keys could be specific to a single table (that is each table has it's own key pool), or the keys could be "shared" among tables such that an `INSERT INTO Table1` might use `Key=100`, and a following `INSERT INTO Table2` would then use `Key=101`.

This key pool had the benefit that the primary key assigned at the client side could also be used as a foreign key in creating inserts into other tables - all on the client side without first committing the transaction if the user ultimately abandons the new data.

I've searched for similar functionality, but I only seem to find database replication and mirroring, not anything about a table of keys.

We are using a shared database and multiple clients running a VB.NET application for data access and creation.

The basic table I had in mind looks something like:

```
CREATE TABLE [KeyPool] (
   [KeyNo] [int] IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   [AssignedTo] [varchar](50) NULL,
   [Status] [nchar](10) NULL,
   [LastTouched] [datetime2] NULL,
)
```

The Status and LastTouched columns would allow for recovery of "lost keys" if garbage collection was desired, but these are not really necessary. In fact, simply having a single row that stores the last key value given to a client would be the minimum requirement: Just hand out keys in blocks of 1000 upon request and increment the counter to know what block to hand out next. However, without the table that is tracking who has what keys, there would be lots of "wasted" key values (which may or may not be an issue depending on the potential number of records expected in the database).

I'm looking for any "standard" methods in SQL Server before I go out and duplicate the effort of creating my own solution.

Comment: So are you saying you want to ensure you use every value? Are you talking about a `SEQUENCE`? If you simply want to ensure a globally unique ID, you can use a `uniqueidentifier`, which can be generated using `NEWID` or `NEWSEQUENTIALID` (the latter for when you're using a Clustered Primary Key).

Comment: If you want to generate keys outside the SQL engine why not use GUIDs? Also with SQL Server 2012 you can use sequences to generate keys before insert.

Comment: GUIDs are large and their space requirements grow as you add references. I would prefer the `SEQUENCE` solution.

Comment: A table with keys like you are describing is not something you want to do in the modern database world. Also, the timestamp datatype is not what you think it is. It has nothing to do with dates or times. It is a synonym for rowversion. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks Sean. I love how datatype names are not what they seem! I'll switch to `datetime2`. As for the table of keys, please keep in mind that I'm looking at a small (read - department level) group of users, but the client application needs to be very responsive. Many applications I see have an unacceptable lag time when creating new records. I'm trying to avoid that, while still assuring data integrity. If there's a modern solution that is easy to implement... well that's why I'm asking the questions. ;)

Comment: You sound like you are quickly going down a very dark hole known as premature optimization. That is the process of making non-standard design decisions to deal with a performance problem that doesn't exist. By far the easiest solution for avoiding collisions is to use an identity. This key pool you are describing has many problems. It has concurrency issues and race conditions. Trying to roll your own here is just not a good idea at all.

Comment: Well I can't take credit for inventing the idea of a key pool. It was used (successfully) in the iAnywhere database to implement a "semi-connected" model where synchronization occurred only when the client had a connection.

I would appreciate if you could expand on what concurrency and race conditions you see, since the entire purpose is to mitigate such issues and provide performance improvements.

I do take your comment about premature optimization to heart. But at the same time, I see too many application with awful performance because it wasn't a design requirement in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Sequence object.  You can use ‘NEXT VALUE FOR’ in a default or query, or request blocks of keys from the client using [sp_sequence_get_range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-sequence-get-range-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Thank you David. So if I understand, the 'SEQUENCE` object would be used to generate my keys, but I still need to store them in a table if I want to track where they are "assigned"?

I can use `CREATE SEQUENCE KeySeq  
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 100` to generate the keys, but then still store them in my `KeyTable`?

Comment: Why track them?  Create a separate Sequence for each table and don’t worry about gaps.

Comment: So I created a test Sequence, and can see it increment when I use `select NEXT VALUE FOR TestRange;`. I see that the information appears in the `sys.sequences` view. But, while this gives me the blocks of numbers I'm look for, I still wonder if I should log the requests for number blocks. One worry I have is that if a client app is not "well behaved" it could make a massive number of requests. If we track usage, we can recycle abandoned key blocks.

Comment: You probably shouldn't write code or make design choices to account for client apps that aren't "well behaved".  You can always treat it as an operational issue if it ever occurs.

Comment: Well I certainly would like to use the tools of the database that are available to assure the database is robust, but it seems to me that design choices (preferably using the features of the DB engine) should focus on performance and reliability. Not accounting for potential client app bugs is exactly why there are so many unreliable projects. I want it designed right, and if key pools are not the tool for the job, I'm happy to learn a better way.

Comment: Just an update for anyone that might come across this post: Per the information here, I ended up abandoning the "key pool" concept in favor of using integer keys set to `IDENTITY(1,1)` and having all queries performed by stored procedures called by the client app(s). When a new record is created, and I need the key, the stored procedure uses `SET @KeyParameter = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())` to pass the new value back.